# Laravel best way to pre-select checkbox fields from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an app that has users and roles.  I want users with the Administrator role to be able to change other user roles.  For example add/remove them from other roles.

To do this, I have setup a form with checkboxes, which lists out all of the user roles available:

**View**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Groups</legend>
    @foreach($roles as $role)
        {!! Form::checkbox($role->field) !!} <span>{{ $role->name }}</span><br>
    @endforeach
</fieldset>
```

This results in the following being produced:

```
[] Administrator
[] Supervisor
[] Employer
[] Contractor
```

I have a method which I use to load roles that the user belongs to:

```
/**
 * Get all user roles.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getUsersRoles($id)
{
    return $this->roleUser->where('user_id', $id)->get();
}
```

The above method returns an object containing each role.

**How can I use this method to pre-select roles which the user belongs to on my view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{!! Form::checkbox($role->field->name, $role->field->id, in_array($role->id, Auth::user()->getUsersRoles()->lists('id'))) !!}
```

You check if the current role id is inside your available user roles. If true the box will be selected.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.  I just had to add `->toArray()` to convert the `lists()` to an array.

Comment: Forgot this little part, sorry :)